# How to add a custom type like Point[] to be able to save data in application settings file?

Tags: c#, arrays, settings

How to save a point array in setting file in C#.

In Proprties the file `settings.setting` have only point, int ,string...

Point[] Does not exist there.

The VS designer creates as Settings class and automatically generates properties based on the setting names but no any array.

Comment: I never got it to work and resorted to storing serialization strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like that:

```
public class Points : List<Point>
{
}
```

Next build the project.

Then you can add this parameter using the Visual Studio wizard by double clicking on `Settings.settings` in the `Properties` section of the project in the solution explorer:

- Add a new named `Points` or `SomePoints` for example.
- Select custom type by browsing and defining as: `TheClassNamespace.Points`.

And you're done.

You need to first initialize the instance and afterward you are able to use it.

For example:

```
private void ButtonCreatePoints_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ( Properties.Settings.Default.Points == null )
    Properties.Settings.Default.Points = new Points();
  Properties.Settings.Default.Points.Add(new Point(10, 10));
  Properties.Settings.Default.Points.Add(new Point(20, 20));
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void ButtonViewPoints_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string str = "";
  foreach ( var point in Properties.Settings.Default.Points )
    str += $"{point.X},{point.Y}" + Environment.NewLine;
  MessageBox.Show(str.TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()));
}
```

On first run if we click on CreatePoints and ViewPoints it shows the created points.

And if we close the app and run it again, clicking on ViewPoints shows the same points that were saved.

You can put the null check to create at the program startup in Main or in the main form constructor or load event... but do that before using this parameter.

If you need to use this parameter as an array, you can write:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Points.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shortcut**

1. In your settings page, add a new entry (say; MyPoints) of `Point` type.

[image]

2. In your project's property folder, locate and open the `Settings.settings` using the notepad or notepad++ as you would like:

[image]

3. Change the type of the MyPoints entry as follow:

From:

```xml
<Setting Name="MyPoints" Type="System.Drawing.Point" Scope="User">
    <Value Profile="(Default)">0, 0</Value>
</Setting>
```

To:

```xml
<Setting Name="MyPoints" Type="System.Drawing.Point[]" Scope="User">
    <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

4. Save and close the file.

Now your new type (Point[]) is among the other types in the settings page.

[image]

Code example:

```cs
var points = new [] { new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 2), new Point(3, 3) };

//Set
Properties.Settings.Default.MyPoints = points;

//Get
points = Properties.Settings.Default.MyPoints;
```

Good luck.